# Where is the Nexus when it's not in our universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *Star Trek: Generations*, what did it mean that the Nexus "enters our universe every 75 years", or something to that effect? I mean, where would it be when it's *not* in our universe?  And how does it travel?

Comment: Can you give a reference to this statement? Who says that it enters our universe every 75 years? When did they say this?

Answer (score 13):

The [quote](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html) from the film (Data's assessment) is that the Nexus is a...

> "...ribbon is a conflux of temporal energy which **travels through this
>   galaxy** every thirty-nine point one years."

So it's not leaving the galaxy, let alone the universe.

This scene (and its dialogue) appear almost identically in the official graphic novelisation:
[image]

---

I couldn't find a reference to it being a gateway to another universe in the theatrical film, but interestingly, that description *does* appear in the [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Generations.html):

> **GUINAN :** *That ribbon isn't just some random energy phenomenon traveling through space... it's a doorway. It leads to another
>   place... the Nexus. It doesn't exist in our Universe... and it doesn't
>   play by the same rules either.*